# Calculate a field in Sub Query using fields of Main Query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm trying to calculate a lapse in products with a SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_NO, START_DT, END_DT, TERM_NO 
FROM DB1.TABLE1
ORDER BY ID_NO, START_DT;
```

I want to calculate the LAPSE when a ID has a second term. It would be the number of days between the `END_DT` of Term 1 and `START_DT` of Term 2.

[image]

I can do this easily in excel. But I'm new writing any advanced SQL. Can I get some direction or any sample to achieve this? I tried to google, but I'm having hard time trying to come up with correct search phrases.

Comment: It can have any number of records with the same ID_NO ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t1.*,
       nullif((start_dt - lag(end_dt) over (partition by id_no order by start_dt)), 0) as lapse
from table1 t1;
```

Comment: simple and elegant.. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple left self join:

```
select
  t.*, t.start_dt - tt.end_dt as lapse
from tablename t left join tablename tt
on tt.id_no = t.id_no and tt.term_no = 1 and t.term_no = 2
```

You may change the `ON` clause to:

```
on tt.id_no = t.id_no and t.term_no - tt.term_no = 1
```

if there are other values also in the column `termo_no` like `1, 2, 3, 4....`

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9308d10334478ea49b010655056e55ff).
Results:

```
ID_NO    | START_DT  | END_DT    | TERM_NO | LAPSE
:------- | :-------- | :-------- | ------: | ----:
48965787 | 13-DEC-17 | 13-DEC-18 |       1 |  
48965787 | 30-DEC-18 | 13-DEC-19 |       2 |    17
57896248 | 17-JAN-18 | 17-JAN-19 |       1 |  
57896248 | 17-JAN-19 | 17-JAN-20 |       2 |     0
78515698 | 16-JUN-18 | 16-JUN-19 |       1 |  
78515698 | 01-AUG-19 | 16-JUN-20 |       2 |    46
```

Comment: Thanks for the help forpas. I tried your solution and it's giving me the result as expected. But my tables are too huge and joining is taking a long time for fewer results. I'm going to use Gordon's method in this instance